# Ionic: Touchstart and Touchend don't trigger on Android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using Ionic v3.0 and trying to create a directive that will cover an element with an overlay when it's touched and remove that overlay once the touch ends. So far I wrote this:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[tappable]' // Attribute selector
})
export class TappableDirective {

  private readonly _overlay;

  constructor(private _elmRef: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer2) {
    this._overlay = _renderer.createElement('div');

    this._renderer.setStyle(this._overlay, 'position', 'absolute');
    this._renderer.setStyle(this._overlay, 'width', '100%');
    this._renderer.setStyle(this._overlay, 'height', '100%');
    this._renderer.setStyle(this._overlay, 'background', '#ffffff00');
    this._renderer.setStyle(this._overlay, 'left', '0');
    this._renderer.setStyle(this._overlay, 'top', '0');
    this._renderer.setStyle(this._overlay, 'display', 'block');
    this._renderer.setStyle(this._overlay, 'transition', '0.2s');

    _renderer.appendChild(_elmRef.nativeElement, this._overlay);
  }

  @HostListener('touchstart')
  tapped() {
    this._renderer.setStyle(this._overlay, 'background', '#ffffff22')
  }

  @HostListener('touchend')
  untapped() {
    this._renderer.setStyle(this._overlay, 'background', '#ffffff00')
  }

}
```

This works just fine when I run my app on an iOS emulator, but it's not the case with Android. It seems that the touchstart and touchend do not get triggered when I interact with the element. Did I miss something here?

Comment: Did you try changing selector to something else? “tappable” used to be reserved by ionic

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I just tried that, no result. I don't think the problem is from the name since it is working on iOS.

Comment: I see. If you add console log to touchstart it does not fire?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko apparently it does! But the styling is not applied.

Comment: ah then I think I know what the problem is;) if you don't figure it I can help

Comment: Figured it out :), posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Looks like changing the opacity using `#ffffff00` to `#ffffff22` does not work in Android. The way to go around it is by using `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)` to `rgba(255, 255, 255, 50)` or changing the `opacity`.